# flake8 behaves differently when run from within a bash script

Tags: bash, git, flake8

I suppose the answer here might be trivial, but I it might require some intricate bash knowledge. I have been browsing bash docs for a few hours now and can't seem to find the answer.

I'm working on a python repository, and came up with a simple script to lint only the files that differ between the current branch and master. Here's the minimal working example, extracted from said script (`lint.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash    
paths=$(git diff --name-only -r origin/master...HEAD | grep \.py$)    
flake8 $paths
```

For testing purposes, let's say I only committed one file, `bad.py`, with the following contents:

```
hello
there
```

The expected output of `bash lint.sh` is:

```
bad.py:1:1: F821 undefined name 'hello'
bad.py:2:1: F821 undefined name 'there'
```

However, the output is empty. When run in debug mode, bash shows the following commands:

```
++ git diff --name-only -r origin/master...HEAD
++ grep '.py$'
+ paths='bad.py'
+ flake8 'bad.py'
```

Which is what I expect. Also, when I simply run `flake8 bad.py`, the output is as expected.

I expect this **might** have something to do with parameter passing which varies between different bash versions. The output of `bash --version`:
`GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0)`

I will appreciate all insights

Comment: Can you show the result of `type -a flake8` from the command line and the script?

Comment: Also try just `flake8 'bad.py'` in the script.

Comment: The output of `type` is in both cases the same:
`flake8 is /Users/path/to/project/venv/bin/flake8
flake8 is /Users/filip/miniconda3/bin/flake8`. Running `flake 'bad.py'` from the script works as expected

Comment: For debugging purposes, can you show the following:
`set -x; python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1:])' $paths` (at the end of your script)

Comment: err sorry, even more useful: `set -x; python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1:])' "$paths"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very sorry this isn't exactly an answer, but it surely didn't fit in a comment!

The hint here to me is the following:

```
+ paths='bad.py'
+ flake8 'bad.py'
```

In my execution of the same script, I get the following:

```
$ bash -x lint.sh 
++ git diff --name-only -r origin/master...HEAD
++ grep '.py$'
+ paths=bar.py
+ flake8 bar.py
bar.py:1:1: F821 undefined name 'hello'
bar.py:2:1: F821 undefined name 'world'
```

Notice here how my output does *not* contain quotes around the filename or the assignment.  `bash` won't usually add quotes unless they are necessary.  What this tells me is there's *probably* some sort of control character in that string (my best guess is either colors or `\b` + some other characters (this might be one of the few cases where a screenshot is actually helpful!)).

Here's one way that I was able to reproduce your findings:

```
mkdir -p bin

cat > bin/grep << EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec /bin/grep --color=always "\$@"
EOF

chmod +x bin/grep

# simulate having this `grep` on your path
PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH bash -x lint.sh
```

(and while this *seems* like an odd thing to do, in the past I've put my own `grep` in `~/bin` so I could add `--line-buffered --color=auto` now that [`GREP_OPTIONS` is deprecated](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html) -- one might erroneously add `--color=always` and have it work... for the most part).  Today I [use an alias](https://github.com/asottile/scratch/blob/f29a8d26c333c985d447d6ad3affd47e292f0902/.bash_aliases#L2) instead since I ran into sharp edges even with that.

The output in that case matches yours above:

```
$ PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH bash -x lint.sh
++ git diff --name-only -r origin/master...HEAD
++ grep '.py$'
+ paths='bar.py'
+ flake8 'bar.py'
```

But the tricky hint is in the highlighting

[image: screenshot of terminal output]

#### addendum

While unrelated to your problem, here's probably a better way to accomplish what you want:

```
# if you have GNU xargs
git diff -z --name-only origin/master...HEAD -- '*.py' | xargs --null --no-run-if-empty flake8

# if you need to be more portable (I see you're probably on macos)
git diff -z --name-only origin/master...HEAD -- '*.py' | xargs -0 flake8 /dev/null
```

Explanation of the different parts:

- **`git diff -z`**: output filenames with null bytes delimiting.  This prevents splicing if filenames contain spaces or other special characters
- **`xargs --null`**: split the input by null bytes when splatting arguments
- **`xargs --no-run-if-empty`**: don't run the executable at all if there's no arguments (this is a GNU extension)
- **`xargs -0`**: same as `xargs --null`, however if you're stuck with non-GNU xargs you won't have access to the long options
- **`flake8 /dev/null`**: this is a sneaky trick, since there's no "no run if empty" option to bsd xargs, it's always going to invoke `flake8`.  If `flake8` gets invoked with zero arguments, it defaults to recursing your current working directory (and linting all your files).  By putting `/dev/null` at the beginning this prevents this behaviour and instead lints an empty file!

Addendum 2, you probably might want to consider using a git hooks framework to handle all of this for you, I maintain [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com) which aims to smooth out a lot of the rough edges around `git` (such as this one!).

Comment: Oh, this is great. It turned out I have `GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'` in my `.bash_profile`, which causes the special characters' presence